# Getting iterations of a split string

Tags: python

Im trying to get the "variants" of a string but I can't wrap my head around on how to do it. Let me explain what I have.

My objective is to get the different variations of a URL. Lets say we have the following URL:

https://www.example.com/index/subindex/subsubindex

Im doing a split with `/`

```
splitURL = str(initialUrl).split('/')
```

So im left with something like this

```
splitURL[0] = 'https:'
splitURL[1] = ''
splitURL[2] = 'www.example.com'
splitURL[3] = 'index'
splitURL[4] = 'subindex'
splitURL[5] = 'subsubindex'
```

Whats the best way to get a list along the lines of
`list = [https://www.example.com/, https://www.example.com/index/, https://www.example.com/index/subindex/, https://www.example.com/index/subindex/subsubindex]`?

I have tried doing a `for items in splitURL` for getting the variants, but the first urls i'd get that way (`https:` for example) are not useful to me.

I have also tried using `for x in range (2,len(urlList)+1)` but I keep getting `indexOutOfBounds` errors.

Any way of doing this in a "nicer" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from 3 to get always `https://www.example.com` till all list will be over, and join with slash

```
res = ['/'.join(splitURL[:x]) for x in range (3,len(splitURL)+1)]

# ['https://www.example.com', 'https://www.example.com/index', 'https://www.example.com/index/subindex', 'https://www.example.com/index/subindex/subsubindex']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) module.

```
from urllib import parse

def paths(path):
    for i, c in enumerate(res.path):
        if c == '/':
             yield path[:i]
    if path:
        yield path

>>> parsed_url = parse.urlparse('https://www.example.com/index/subindex/subsubindex')
>>> [f'{parsed_url.scheme}://{parsed_url.hostname}{p}' for p in paths(parsed_url.path)]
['https://www.example.com', 
 'https://www.example.com/index', 
 'https://www.example.com/index/subindex', 
 'https://www.example.com/index/subindex/subsubindex']
```